# Should I give feedback on my performance review if there's nothing negative to say?

Tags: performance-reviews, feedback

I've been an intern for 3 months and now my boss has a performance review and I'm supposed to give some feedback. It's not obligatory though.

I would only have positive things to say (so far), but I don't want the upper management or my boss to think I'm not being truthful (or sucking up.).

Should I give any feedback at all and what is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, give feedback.  It's perfectly possible to be positive in your feedback without looking like you're sucking up to your boss/manager.

A good way to do this is to mention specifics and report on:

- Communication
- Suitability of your tasks and how they match your skills
- What your manager was like in feeding back to you when you completed tasks
- How well you were integrated into the team

Don't feel as though you need to search for negatives to provide a balanced view.  It's really good to report that you're happy in your new job.

Comment: Despites some evidences tell the contrary, managers are human, too. And humans like positive feedback.

Comment: Agreed, also, if you have anything that you would like to see in addition to the already great things you have, or if you have any other improvement suggestions, this is the time to voice them - like "we do have a kicker in the break room, which I like, how about a coffee machine there, currently we always have to walk to the kitchen in the first floor first"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, give positive feedback.

Sometimes a person will do something well/effectively, but not even be aware of it (speaking from experience). The only way they will know they're doing that thing well is if someone gives them feedback.

If someone is really good at their job, you can always tell them what positive aspects of the way they work really sets them apart, or that you appreciate the most.